# Using stacks to solve tower of Hanoi (java)

Tags: java, stack, towers-of-hanoi

```
public static enum Action {
    No, LToM, MToL, MToR, RToM
}

public static int hanoiProblem2(int num, String left, String mid, String right) {
    Stack<Integer> lS = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> mS = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> rS = new Stack<Integer>();
    lS.push(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    mS.push(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    rS.push(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
        lS.push(i);
    }
    Action[] record = { Action.No };
    int step = 0;
    while (rS.size() != num + 1) {
        step += fStackTotStack(record, Action.MToL, Action.LToM, lS, mS, left, mid);
        step += fStackTotStack(record, Action.LToM, Action.MToL, mS, lS, mid, left);
        step += fStackTotStack(record, Action.RToM, Action.MToR, mS, rS, mid, right);
        step += fStackTotStack(record, Action.MToR, Action.RToM, rS, mS, right, mid);
    }
    return step;
}

public static int fStackTotStack(Action[] record, Action preNoAct,
                                 Action nowAct, Stack<Integer> fStack, Stack<Integer> tStack,
                                 String from, String to) {
    if (record[0] != preNoAct && fStack.peek() < tStack.peek()) {
        tStack.push(fStack.pop());
        System.out.println("Move " + tStack.peek() + " from " + from + " to " + to);
        record[0] = nowAct;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 4;

    // solution 2
    int steps2 = hanoiProblem2(num, "left", "mid", "right");
    System.out.println("It will move " + steps2 + " steps.");
    System.out.println("===================================");

}
```

This is a code for solving tower of Hanoi. It uses three stacks to simulate 3 towers.
My question is that why does it define the record variable as an array?
Action[] record = { Action.No };
record[0] = nowAct;

I tried to change them to
Action record =  Action.No;
record = nowAct;
then the code is failed to run.

I don't know the reason. I really appreciate it if someone could explain the reason.
Thanks.

Comment: I forget to mention there is one more condition in this question: the disk cannot be moved from left to right or from right to left in one step. It must be left to middle to right or right to middle to left.

Comment: `{ Action.No }` is an array containing one element, type `Action[]`. It is not the same as `Action.No`, type `Action`.

Comment: I mean it only used record[0]. Could I change 'record' to a variable from an array? Thank you.

Comment: Change `Action[] record = { Action.No };` to `Action record = Action.No`, and change the stack to stack method to `Action record`. Then you can just use `record` instead of `record[0]` See: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays

Comment: I did, but it would be in an infinite loop...

Comment: There is a warning on 'record = nowAct;' line in stack to stack method. The value nowAct assigned to 'record' is never used

Comment: Yeah, I should have read it more carefully. It's an array because the value is being changed every time it's being called. I'll explain what's going on in an answer.

Comment: So it means I have to use an array in this situation? Could you explain more about the reason? I am a newbie in Java programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `record` is being defined as an array because its value is being changed within the `fStackTotStack` method.

The simplest explanation for this is because Java passes variables by *value*, not by *reference*. It passes Object references by value as well.

Take, for example, the following code:

```
public void foo(int bar) {
  bar += 4;
  System.out.println("Foo's bar: " + bar);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int bar = 5;
  new Foo().foo(bar);
  System.out.println("Main's bar: " + bar);
}
```

This will print out:

```
Foo's bar: 9 
Main's bar: 5
```

This is because the `bar` variable inside the `foo` function is a different variable than the one inside the `main` function. The value is just copied over when the method is called.

When you pass an array, the variables themselves are still different:

```
public void foo(int[] bar) {
  bar = new int[]{9};
  System.out.println("Foo's bar: " + bar[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] bar = {5};
  new Foo().foo(bar);
  System.out.println("Main's bar: " + bar[0]);
}
```

This will yield the same results as before, because foo's bar is different than main's bar.

However, Object references are passed by value. This means that while the variables are different, the values they represent are the same. Therefore this:

```
public void foo(int[] bar) {
  bar[0] += 4;
  System.out.println("Foo's bar: " + bar[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] bar = {5};
  new Foo().foo(bar);
  System.out.println("Main's bar: " + bar[0]);
}
```

Will print out something different than before:

```
Foo's bar: 9 
Main's bar: 9
```

This is because while foo's `bar` variable and main's `bar` variable are different variables, they point to the same underlying object. So, changes to the object itself, and not just the variable, will persist.

In your example above, the line `Action[] record = { Action.No };` is creating an array that gets passed into the `fStackTotStack` method. Since the variable `record` is not being changed itself (there is no `record = new Action[] {}` anywhere), the array it points to is still the same one that was passed. This means that you can make changes to the object itself (in this case, an array).

[Here is an article that can explain it better than I can.](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html)